# Regular Expression (Regex) Possitive lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm looking regex that not include the beginning string (this part I get fine) and exclude the final string that sometimes has a number xxx,xx or has two numbers xxx,xx xxx,xx (see the image).

But my expression - `(?<=[0-3][0-9] [0-1][0-9] [2][2-9] 7[\d]{3} ).*(?= [\d]{1,5},[\d]{2} ?([\d]{1,5},[\d]{2})?)` fails in case like this:

```
23 06 22 7314 VIAJES EL CORTE INGL 13389,00 5357,15
```

I can not exclude `13389,00`. Can somebody help me?

See my [regex playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcznt.png).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: As per the [ask], please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: while it isn't clear what you're trying to do here (you need to provide a code snippet, or at least some examples of what it should match), the pattern will surely work better if that middle "wildcard" is non-greedy: `.*?`

Comment: `(?<=[0-3][0-9] [0-1][0-9] [2][2-9] 7[\d]{3})\s(.*?)\s(?:\d{1,5}\,\d{2})`

Answer (score 0):

According to your question and the attached screenshot, I think if your input is:

case-I: `'VAIAJES EL CORTE INGL 13389,00 5357,15'; then output: 13389,00`

case-II: `'VAIAJES EL CORTE INGL 13389,00'; then output: 13389,00`

This is my understanding, if not then please correct me and describe it properly.

Use regular expression ("Positive Lookahead"): `/(?<=[\w+\s+])(\d+\,\d+)/gi` to  filter the number in format '(\d+,\d+)'.

and used the regular expression as:
`text.match(/(?<=[\w+\s+])(\d+\,\d+)/gi)?.length ? text.match(/(?<=[\w+\s+])(\d+\,\d+)/gi)[0] : null`
[image]

If you want to get first numbers in this input:
`'VAIAJES EL CORTE INGL 13389,00 5357,15'`

Then use the regular expression (Lookahead and Lookbehind) like: `/(?<=[\w+\s+])(\d+\,\d+)(?=([\d+\,]+\s))/gi`
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake. I want get only the phrase "VIAJES EL CORTE INGLES". I want discard 13389,00 5357,15 or 13389,00. My regex discard correctly if has only 13389,00 but when contains  13389,00 5357,15 I get the phrase VIAJES EL CORTE INGLES 13389,00"

Comment: Use regular expression: `/[a-z ]+(?=(\s[0-9\,]+))/gi` to get only text.

```
'VAIAJES EL CORTE INGL 13389,00 5357,15'.match(/[a-z ]+(?=(\s[0-9\,]+))/gi)
output: ['VAIAJES EL CORTE INGL']



'VAIAJES EL CORTE INGL 13389,00'.match(/[a-z ]+(?=(\s[0-9\,]+))/gi)
output: ['VAIAJES EL CORTE INGL']
```